# Behat/Mink/Selenium2 element is not visible

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, selenium, behat, mink

I'm writing my tests with behat and I'm facing a problem when I try to call fillField on a input inside a bootstrap modal.
When I send fillField in this input selenium throws an exception saying:

```
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

I've created a selenium (via selenium IDE) test manually and called type on the same field and it worked fine.

```
$page = $this->getSession()->getPage()
$page->fillField("id_item", $value);
```

The `$value` is a parameter from my test. I've tried to call a function to wait some seconds, but it didn't worked as well.

**UPDATE:**

Scenario:

```
Scenario: Realizar Pedido de Compra
Given I am on "/"
When I fill the form with "{\"id\": 1, \"items\":[{\"id_item\": 1}]}"
Then I should see "Ok"
```

My FeatureContext:

```
/**
 * @When I fill the form with :arg1
 */
public function iFillForm($json) {
    $formHelper = FormHelper::getInstance($this->getSession());
    $formHelper->fill($json);
}
```

In my class FormHelper:

```
public function fill($json) {
    $handler = new SelectorsHandler();
    $handler->registerSelector("css", new CssSelector());
    $fileJson = json_decode($json, true);
    $page = $this->session->getPage();
    foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
       if (is_array($value)) {
          $addSubGrid = $page->find("css", "#btn-plus-" . $key);
          if ($addSubGrid != null) {
             $subGrid = $page->find("css", "#" . $key);
             $formId = $subGrid->getAttribute("data-form");
             $ok = $page->find("css", "#$formId .btn-ok");
             foreach ($value as $formItem) {
                $itemFilled = array();
                $addSubGrid->click();
                $this->session->wait(
                   1000, "$('#modal-$formId').is(':visible')"
                );
                $this->fillForm($page, array("form-item" => $formItem), $itemFilled, false);
                $ok->press();
             }
          }
       } else {
          $page->fillField($key, $value);
       }
    }
```

The `$addSubGrid` var is the elment to show the modal. When I execute the test it opens the modal but when it goes into `$page->fillField($key, $value)` it does not work.

**UPDATE**
I've found that I was trying to fill a disabled field. I've enabled it and the problem now is that it does not fill the fields inside the modal, just the ones outside.

Comment: Show the scenario code?

Comment: Hey. I've added the scenario and the code that runs it

Comment: @ThiagoFrança I use the one from Behat (I've followed their docs)
@IanBytchek the error ocurs on `fillField` after it opens the modal using `$addSubGrid->click()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve this using the setValue from the driver manually. It seems there's a bug with fillField from mink.
I've used:

```
$this->session->getDriver()->setValue('//*[@id="'.$key.'"]', $value);
```

instead of

```
$page->fillField($key, $value);
```

Comment: Strange, I thought there's just a little mixup somewhere – everything looked rather neat. Take a moment to [report it](https://github.com/Behat/Mink/issues), guys might have further comments on this.

Comment: I've created an issue there. Thanks :)

Comment: I am still experiencing issues with this. Just to post a comment for timeline if you are looking at this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with "hidden" check/radio boxes designed using "custom icons" instead of "native components" like shown here http://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/yILjk

Solution for my problem was to set native components to "visible" before cliking:

```
private function checkMyBox($locator)
{
    $this->getSession()->executeScript("
                var element = document.getElementById('".$locator."');
                element.style.opacity = 1;
                element.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=100)'; //iexplorer!
                element.style.visibility = 'visible'
            ");
    $this->getSession()->wait(2000);

    $this->getSession()->getPage()->findField($locator)->click();
}
```

In my case it was "opacity" and "visibility" but you should check following css-options (inspect the field in your browser):

```
visibility != hidden
display != none
opacity != 0
height and width are both > 0
type != hidden (on input fields)
```

I'm using Selenium2, Behat and Mink and i hope this code snippet will help someone fixing similar problems.