# Behat Test Stripe Form

Tags: bdd, behat

I am trying to test a Stripe form with Behat. With stripe forms you cannot have `name` attributes to prevent sensitive data hitting your server. That being said the `fillField` method of Behat is supposed to look for `id`, `title` and `label` but is not working.

Here is my code:

```
public function iPurchaseListings($quantity)
{
    $this->visit('/account/billing');
    $this->fillField('number', '4242424242424242');
    $this->fillField('exp_month', '01');
    $this->fillField('exp_year', '2018');
    $this->fillField('cvc', '123');
    $this->fillField('quantity', $quantity);
    $this->pressButton('submit');
}
```

Currently these are the `ids` of the fields. If I add a `name` attribute it will work. If I do not add a name field I always get a `Malformed field path` exception.

I have also tried the solution [located here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239561/behat-mink-selenium2-element-is-not-visible/26242599#comment45847569_26242599)

Any help would be amazing.  I'm going crazy over here.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong!

> Behat is supposed to look for id, title and label but is not working.

It looks for `id, name or label` of locator as described in [documentation](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/Behat/Mink/source-class-Behat.Mink.Element.TraversableElement.html#150-169) or check [this](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/blob/master/src/Behat/MinkExtension/Context/MinkContext.php#L105). Also see DocBloc below.

**TraversableElement Class**

```
 /**
  * Fills in field (input, textarea, select) with specified locator.
  *
  * @param string $locator input id, name or label
  * @param string $value   value
  *
  * @throws ElementNotFoundException
  *
  * @see NodeElement::setValue
  */
 public function fillField($locator, $value)
 {
     $field = $this->findField($locator);

     if (null === $field) {
         throw $this->elementNotFound('form field', 'id|name|label|value', $locator);
     }

     $field->setValue($value);
 }
```

**EXAMPLE**

**FeatureContext Class**

```
/**
 * @Given /^I am logged in as admin$/
 */
public function iAmLoggedInAsAdmin()
{
    $this->visit('/admin');
    $this->fillField('username', 'admin');
    $this->fillField('password', 'admin');
    $this->pressButton('Login');
    $this->assertPageContainsText('Welcome Admin');
}
```

I've just tried these and all worked fine.

```
<input type="text" id="username" value="" />
<input type="text" name="username" value="" />
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" />
<input type="text" id="password" value="" />
<input type="text" name="password" value="" />
<input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="" />
```

**BACKUP OPTION FOR YOU**

```
   /**
     * @When /^I fill in "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/
     *
     * @param $id
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function iClickAnElementWithId($id, $value)
    {
        $element = $this->getSession()->getPage()->findById($id);
        if (null === $element) {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf('Could not evaluate element with ID: "%s"', $id));
        }
        $element->setValue();

    }
```

If it still doesn't work then to be honest I don't know what to say. Also you might be better off testing it with a very basic/plain application to see if it is actually to do with your webform/application or not.